# Working media player for VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, video, vlc-media-player

I use VirtualBox 4.18 and I'd like to play various video files (various codecs like Xvid and x264, various containers like AVI and MKV).
Unfortunately, the following players cannot render Direct3D surface (to show both video and subtitle):

- Media Player Classic 1.7.7
- VLC Player 2.1

They can create a software rendered surface but it looks very ugly and there is no subtitle rendering. Can you suggest a working media player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the perfect solution but it works:

**In VLC 2.1 set the video output to Direct2D**